# Search across cells and return value from different cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I need to reference a cell based on drop-down values from four different columns.

Essentially I am trying to compile a summary list of data from different tabs. Each tab is laid out the same however on this new summary I need to pull the data from A2 based on a value in D2:G2. I have tried so many different formulas to no avail. I've come closest with:

```
=INDEX(Assessments!D2:G2,MATCH(TRUE,A1,Assessments!A2),0)
```

This return the #VALUE message stating that parameter 3 expects number values but "NAME" is a text and cannot be coerced into a number.

and

```
=vlookup($A$1,{Assessments!D2:G2,Assessments!A2},1,0)
```

This returns the value in A1 however, I actually need it to return the text from Assessments!A2

Data sets:

| Name | Launch | Description | Tag | Tag | Tag | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Assement Title A | rd_28 | Testing | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |  |
| Assement Title B | rd_28 | Testing | Enhance | Embrace |  |  |
| Assement Title C | rd_28 | Testing | Enhance | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |
| Assement Title D | rd_28 | Testing | Embrace |  |  |  |
| Assement Title E | rd_28 | Testing | Embrace | Educate |  |  |
| Assement Title F | rd_28 | Testing | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |  |
| Assement Title G | rd_28 | Testing | Enhance | Embrace |  |  |
| Assement Title H | rd_28 | Testing | Enhance | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |
| Assement Title I | rd_28 | Testing | Enlighten | Embrace |  |  |
| Assement Title J | rd_28 | Testing | Enhance |  |  |  |
| Assement Title K | rd_28 | Testing | Embrace | Educate |  |  |
| Assement Title L | rd_28 | Testing | Enhance |  |  |  |

This information would ideally be pulled into a new sheet with the following column headers: (A1 = Enhance)

| Enhance | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Once I have all the assessment data in a linear format, I'd need to use the formula again to pull data from the other tabs, such as:

| Name | Launch | Description | Tag | Tag | Tag | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doc Title A | rd_1 | Testing | Enlighten | Embrace |  |  |
| Doc Title B | rd_1 | Testing | Enhance | Embrace | Educate |  |
| Doc Title C | rd_1 | Testing | Enhance | Enlighten | Embrace |  |
| Doc Title D | rd_1 | Testing | Embrace | Educate |  |  |
| Doc Title E | rd_1 | Testing | Embrace | Educate | Enhance |  |
| Doc Title F | rd_1 | Testing | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |  |
| Doc Title G | rd_1 | Testing | Enhance | Embrace |  |  |
| Doc Title H | rd_1 | Testing | Enhance | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |
| Doc Title I | rd_1 | Testing | Enlighten | Embrace | Enhance |  |
| Doc Title J | rd_1 | Testing | Educate |  |  |  |
| Doc Title K | rd_1 | Testing | Embrace | Educate |  |  |
| Doc Title L | rd_1 | Testing | Enhance |  |  |  |

Comment: To minimize confusion, try to limit your ask to one question. I think part of your problem is you are trying to pull data from a pivoted table. Perhaps if you unpivot you may find a formula like `Filter` suitable for your needs.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you want the summary table to look like. Do you want a list of all assessment titles per tag? E.g. "Assessment Title B" should appear twice in the new sheet, once under "Enhance" column and once under "Embrace" column?

Comment: Yes, exacly! I would need a list of all assessment titles per tag. I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: It's not a pivoted table... each of the "Tag" columns is a data validation>list of items dropdown. I included that information in my question only because I wasn't sure if that could have any impact on the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the standard lookup functions will work because

1. You need to search multiple tag columns for the same value
2. You need to return multiple row numbers if there is more than one  match (not just the first one)

To achieve this, you need to use array functions. The new Office 365 / Google sheets array functions will come in very handy:

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(INDEX(Assessments!$A$2:$A$21,BYROW(A$1=Assessments!$D$2:$G$21,LAMBDA(x,2*OR(x)-1))*ROW($A$1:$A$20)),"")),,",")
```

Explanation:

```
A$1=Assessments!$D$2:$G$21
```

Returns a boolean matrix of matches against the tag header.

```
BYROW(..., LAMBDA(x, 2*OR(x)-1)
```

Takes this matrix row by row, and OR's the row elements together (i.e. there is a match in that row) and returns a column vector that is 1 if there's a match in the row and -1 if not.

```
BYROW(...)*ROW($A$1:$A$20)
```

Turns the -1 and +1's into row numbers, which can be used as an index into the assessment names (negatives will return an error)

```
IFERROR(INDEX(..., BYROW(...)*ROW(...)), "")
```

Return a column vector of assessment names, with empty "" in rows with no match.

```
TEXTSPIT(TEXTJOIN(...)...)
```

First joins the column vector together as text, separating with comma's and ignoring the empty no-matches. Then splits the text back into a shorter column vector, no only containing the matching names.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I've used the formula and am now receiving a #VALUE that parameter 3 expects a boolean value but ',' is a text and cannot be coerced to a boolean.

Comment: Works for me as is in Excel 365. Make sure the formula matches your localization settings (e.g. "text" vs. 'text' and separators , vs ; etc.). Also, if your names contain commas, you might need to change the TEXTSPLIT/JOIN separators to something else like "|".

Comment: Also, are you using google sheets? Have a google for "how to use array formula in google sheets". It might be that you need to press ctrl+shift+enter or wrap the whole thing in ARRAYFORMULA(...).

Comment: Thank you, thank you!!!